# A urn contains blue balls and red balls. I need to find probabiltiy of drawing more blue balls than red balls

Tags: probability

> A urn contains 5 identical blue balls and 4 identical red balls. Taking 5 balls at random from the urn what is the probability that the number of blue balls be greater than the number of red balls?

My first guess was setting the ways that I can draw the balls.

It was:

> $\color{blue} {BBBBB}$ ; $\color{blue} {BBBB}\color{red}{R}$; $\color{blue} {BBB}\color{red}{RR}$; $\color{blue} {BB}\color{red}{RRR}$; $\color{blue} {B}\color{red}{RRRR}$

Only $3$ cases have the number of blue balls greater than the number of red balls. Then the odds must be $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{5}}$.

But this answer sounds strange for me. I think that it is wrong?

Could anyone help me how to figure out this question?

Comment: Firstly, you have listed the possibilities of taking out 5 balls.

Comment: sorry, I made a typo in the question. Actually, the number of balls is 5 not 4.

Comment: Secondly, do you think each from those possibilities are equally probable?  (In other words, you have just listed the events of drawing blue balls before red balls; what about other drawing orders?)

Comment: Two potential difficulties. (1) You don't have all the arrangements. (2) There are more blue balls in the urn than red ones, so do you suppose BBBBB and BRRRR are equally likely? // Also, are balls drawn with or without repleacement? Usually with urns, it's without replacement. That's what I assumed in my Answer. if it's _with_ replacement, then the relevant distribution in binomial, not hypergeometric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three approaches:

(1) This can be viewed as a hypergeometric distribution. The urn contiains
four red balls and five blue balls. Let $X$ be the number of red balls
among five balls drawn at random without replacement. To draw more blue balls
then red you need to evaluate $P(X \le 2).$  In R statistical software
this can be evaluated as follows:

```
phyper(2, 4, 5, 5)
## 0.6428571
```

(2) The equivalent answer can be obtained using a combinatorial argument:

$$\frac{{4 \choose 0}{5 \choose 5}+{4\choose 1}{5 \choose 4}+{4 \choose 2}{5 \choose 3}}{{9 \choose 5}} = \frac{1 + 20 + 60}{126} = 81/126 = 9/14 = 0.6428571$$

(3) An approximate value (to about 3 places) from simulating a million draws of five balls from
such an urn and counting the red balls can be obtained as follows:

```
set.seed(616)
m = 10^6;  urn = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)    # 1 = blue, 2 = red
r = replicate(m, sum(sample(urn, 5)==2)) # sample 5 balls without replacement
mean(r <= 2)                             # mean of logical vector is nr of TRUEs
## 0.642822
```

The histogram below shows the simulated hypergeometric distribution of the number of red balls drawn. The open red dots show exact hypergeometric probabilities.
At the scale of the graph, it is not easy to see any difference between the
simulated and exact values.

[image]

*Note:* You should be sure you understand and can explain the details of either method (1) or method (2) for your class. The simulation is probably not something you are expected to know.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint

There are *$31$ permutations* for selecting $5$ balls:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{blue}{B} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} & \color{red}{R} \\
 \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{red}{R} & \color{blue}{B} \\
\end {array}
\right)$$

(Was too long to post as a comment, my apologies)

Comment: Are you sure permutations are equally likely? Suppose you were drawing only two balls: BB, BR, RB, RR. Are these equally likely outcomes? There are more blue balls than red in the urn.